# Linking two datasets

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset called "J_BL5H1", this includes :

```
Var1    Freq
4   10
8   10
10  13
11  7
13  3
17  10
19  10
25  1
26  4
27  8
53  13
```

From this dataset, I want to find all Var1s seperately, and I want to called this new data like J_BL5H1JNVar1Number, here Var1Number denotes to specific Var1s, e.g. "4, 8, 10".

I will use this :

```
J_BL5H1JNVar1Number <- J_BL5H1$Freq[1]
```

Here, I want to replace Var1Number to "Var1" values in the old data.

For example, if I want to know the "Freq[4]", my new data should be called like "J_BL5H1JN11", the "Var1Number" will be automatically replaced by the Var1 of Freq[4], in this case by 11.

I hope I can clearly state my problem, Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? There might be a much more efficient approach than creating lots of objects in your workspace if you can describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually I solved the problem, but I can talk about anyway. I'm trying to create a dataset for each "Var1" value. This new dataset will only contain the "Freq" value. I want to avoid writing all different "Var1" values in to the place of"Var1Number" :
    J_BL5H1JNVar1Number <- J_BL5H1$Freq[1]

So, I just want to automate these steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `paste` to create the names of the data.sets:

```
 data.string <- "J_BL5H1LN"
 split.var <- "Var1"
 data.sets <- paste(data.string, J_BL5H1[, split.var], sep = "")
```

Then use a loop to `assign` the according values to the data sets:

```
 for( i in seq_along(data.sets) ) assign(data.sets[i], J_BL5H1[i, "Freq"])
```

Now you have the data sets in your workspace:

```
ls()
```

Btw, if you want to access the different data sets without actually calling them every time, you can access them by name using the `get` function:

```
sapply(data.sets, get)
```

Comment: the output is like this : J_BL5H1Var14. Instead of "JN4", there is "Var14". How can I fix that ?

Comment: I changed the code, basically you just have to change the arguments to `paste`